# What is the group of the Lie algebra generated by $\{a(E_{12}-E_{21}),u E_{13},v E_{23}\}$?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

I was asked in an exam to find $G$, if $$Lie(G)=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}0 &-a&u\\ a &0&v\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}; a,u,v\in\mathbb{R}\right\},$$ where $[\cdot,\cdot]$ is the commutator.

My idea was the following: Let $B(t)\in G\forall t\in (-\epsilon,\epsilon)$ and $\epsilon>0$ such that $B(0)=1_{3\times 3}$, then $$\left.\frac{d}{d t}\right|_{t=0}B(t)\in Lie(G).$$ From this I thought that matrices of the following forms could be elements in $G$
$$\begin{bmatrix}1 &-ta&tu\\ ta &1&tv\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0 &-ta&tu\\ ta &0&tv\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}, \text{etc.}$$
The problem with this is that none of them actually satisfy the properties of a group. Can someone maybe explain how one could find a possible group for the given Lie-Algebra.

Comment: Shouldn't $\{ e^A \mid A\in \mathit{Lie}(G) \}$ ought to work when the bracket is the ordinary commutator?

Answer (score 2):

Calculating the eigenvalues of the matrix $$
M(a,u,v)=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -a & u\\
a & 0 & v\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}\Longrightarrow \det (M-\lambda I)=-\lambda(\lambda-ia)(\lambda+ia)
$$
(don't worry too much by the imaginary eigenvalues, everything ends up being rela at the end). Locally the Lie group $G$ is obtained from Lie algebra by exponentiation.
Now by Cayley-Hamiltonian theorem, there exists $c,d,e\in \mathbb{C}$ such that
$$
X(a,u,v):=\exp(M(a,u,v))= cI + dM + eM^2
$$
Assuming $a\neq 0$, using the eigenvalues (and replacing them instead of $M$) we find
$$
\begin{cases}
1=c\\
e^{ia}=c+iad-a^2e\\
e^{-ia} = c-iad-a^2e
\end{cases}\Longrightarrow d = \frac{\sin a}{a}, \qquad e=\frac{1-\cos a}{a^2}
$$
So,
$$
X(a,u,v)= \begin{pmatrix}
\cos a & -\sin a& [u\sin a-v(1-\cos a)]/a\\
\sin a &\cos a & [v\sin a+u(1-\cos a)]/a\\
0& 0& 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
The case $a=0$ can be obtained through taking the limit $a\to 0$. Note that, 
$$
a^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}
u \sin a -v(1-\cos a)\\
u(1-\cos a) + v\sin a
\end{pmatrix}=
\frac{\sin (\frac{a}{2})}{\frac{a}{2}}
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos (\frac{a}{2}) & -\sin (\frac{a}{2})\\
\sin (\frac{a}{2}) & \cos (\frac{a}{2})
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
u\\
v
\end{pmatrix}
$$
The matrix on the right hand side is a rotation matrix multiplied by a non-zero number and hence invertible. This means, your $G$ is nothing but the group of matrices of the form
$$
\boxed{G=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}
\cos a & -\sin a & x\\
\sin a & \cos a & y\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}\: :\: a,x,y\in \mathbb{R}\right\}}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Observe that the matrices in your Lie algebra have a block form with a skew symmetric $2\times 2$-block and a block which is $\mathbb R^2$. Then recall that the skew symmetric $2\times 2$ matrices are the Lie algebra of $O(2)$ and of $SO(2)$.